# Get OpenLayers 3 to load more than one WKT feature

Tags: openlayers

I have OL3 loading a wkt feature from a string here:
http://codepen.io/vbahole/pen/GqWQdJ

I'm now trying to load two WKT features at once using the format.readFeatures() method. But i can't get it to work and I don't know what format OL wants that wkt string to be in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the mulitpolygon type and so plot your features as unique multi-geometry. Here is an example to plot 2 polygons as one multi-polygon.

`var wktManyString = "MULTIPOLYGON (((-18000000 9000000,-16000000 10000000,-15000000 8000000,-17000000 9000000)), ((-17000000 8000000,-16000000 10000000,-15000000 8000000,-17000000 9000000)))";`

Onother option is parse each geometry individualy. something like that for example

```
var wkt1 = 'POLYGON ((-18000000 9000000,-16000000 10000000,-15000000 8000000,-17000000 9000000))';
var wkt2 = 'POLYGON ((-17000000 9000000,-16000000 10000000,-15000000 8000000,-17000000 9000000))';


 var extent;
 var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: new ol.source.Vector({
     loader: function() {
       var format = new ol.format.WKT();
       var s = vector.getSource();
       var f1 = format.readFeature(wkt1, {
         dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
         featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
       });
       var f2 = format.readFeature(wkt2, {
         dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
         featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
       });
       extent = f1.getGeometry();
       s.addFeatures([f1,f2]);
       map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());
     }
     //,projection: 'EPSG:3857'
   })
   //,projection: 'EPSG:3857'
 });
```